# Getting client domain/username over external internet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get an identifier for a client accessing my application over the internet, rather than inside a domain. This will be used to perform an LDAP query. Is this possible, and is anything close to the UserPrincipleName exposed through the browser? Alternatively, can a browser be configured to expose the UPN in order to be picked up with `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName`?

If not, what identifier can I pull from the client browser in order to perform a lookup?

Finally, what are the security implications of using this approach? For clarity, the LDAP server is intended to be inside the client firewall, with exposure to our machines alone. The application will be domain agnostic, as it will be required te serve multiple organisations.

Comment: Over the internet -> LDAP query, seems difficult

Comment: Over the intranet -> Windows Authentication -> seems doable

Comment: Adding OAuth authentication to your application ( from Azure) -> seems doable -> you could even use the Graph API of microsoft to get information then. Not suitable for funtional accounts

Comment: That would rely on the client being enrolled with Azure AD - which is a gamble. The LDAP query isn't a problem - all it requires is exposing the LDAP server to our machines over the internet, then properly implementing LDAPS (LDAP over SSL). It's getting an identifier with which to form the query that is proving difficult.